# Placeholders instead of labels in contribution forms

Tags: forms

I created a Contribution page using Drupal webforms. For esthetics, I am only using placeholders and no field labels. I'd like to do the same for the Credit Card fields that are pulled in from Civi. Is there a simple way to use the field names as placeholders rather than field labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah - no there is not - those fields are grabbed from CiviCRM - as is :-(

So you can't edit them via the Webform tab; If I was heading this way I'd look at a drupal hook_form_alter